# Google Tag Manager класс ContainerLoadedCallback

Tags: java, android, google-analytics

Добрый день!
Пытаюсь настроить *Google Tag Manager* в своем приложении для android.
Делаю по мануалу https://developers.google.com/tag-manager/android/v4/

Добавляя в onCreate

```
pending.setResultCallback(new ResultCallback<ContainerHolder>() {
    @Override
    public void onResult(ContainerHolder containerHolder) {
        ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
        Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
        if (!containerHolder.getStatus().isSuccess()) {
            Log.e("CuteAnimals", "failure loading container");
            displayErrorToUser(R.string.load_error);
            return;
        }
        ContainerHolderSingleton.setContainerHolder(containerHolder);
        ContainerLoadedCallback.registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
        containerHolder.setContainerAvailableListener(new ContainerLoadedCallback());
        startMainActivity();
    }
}, 2, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
```

по инструкции вручную создается класс `ContainerHolderSingleton`, но класc `ContainerLoadedCallback` Android Studio у меня не видит.

В примере в мануале в импорте есть строки которые не добавились автоматически.

```
import com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.Container.FunctionCallMacroCallback;
import com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.Container.FunctionCallTagCallback;
```

Тем не менее, если я добавляю эти строки вручную, они не используются (unused import statement).

Где найти описание этого класса, или как его загрузить?

код `ContainerHolderSingleton`

```
import com.google.android.gms.tagmanager.ContainerHolder;

/**
 * Singleton to hold the GTM Container (since it should be only created once
 * per run of the app).
 */
public class ContainerHolderSingleton {
    private static ContainerHolder containerHolder;

    /**
     * Utility class; don't instantiate.
     */
    private ContainerHolderSingleton() {
    }

    public static ContainerHolder getContainerHolder() {
        return containerHolder;
    }

    public static void setContainerHolder(ContainerHolder c) {
        containerHolder = c;
    }
}
```

Comment: в мануале нету `FunctionCallMacroCallback` и `FunctionCallTagCallback` покажите тогда код вашей `ContainerHolderSingleton`

Comment: Вы включили зависимость     `dependencies {
        compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
    }`

Comment: да, 
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:22.1.1'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нашел здесь https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29534086/android-google-tag-manager-v4-containerloadedcallback

```
private static class ContainerLoadedCallback implements ContainerHolder.ContainerAvailableListener {
    @Override
    public void onContainerAvailable(ContainerHolder containerHolder, String containerVersion) {
        // We load each container when it becomes available.
        Container container = containerHolder.getContainer();
        registerCallbacksForContainer(container);
    }

    public static void registerCallbacksForContainer(Container container) {
        // Register two custom function call macros to the container.
        container.registerFunctionCallMacroCallback("increment", new CustomMacroCallback());
        container.registerFunctionCallMacroCallback("mod", new CustomMacroCallback());
        // Register a custom function call tag to the container.
        container.registerFunctionCallTagCallback("custom_tag", new CustomTagCallback());
    }
}

private static class CustomMacroCallback implements FunctionCallMacroCallback {
    private int numCalls;

    @Override
    public Object getValue(String name, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        if ("increment".equals(name)) {
            return ++numCalls;
        } else if ("mod".equals(name)) {
            return (Long) parameters.get("key1") % Integer.valueOf((String) parameters.get("key2"));
        } else {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Custom macro name: " + name + " is not supported.");
        }
    }
}

private static class CustomTagCallback implements FunctionCallTagCallback {
    @Override
    public void execute(String tagName, Map<String, Object> parameters) {
        // The code for firing this custom tag.
        Log.i("CuteAnimals", "Custom function call tag :" + tagName + " is fired.");
    }
```